# Problem only in Vista (.net): call unmanaged dll(Shell32.dll, function: SHEmptyRecycleBin) from thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, dll, pinvoke, unmanaged

********Platform: in Vista(ultimate or home/premium) it does not work, other OS(xp, windows7) it works***********

I'm emptying recycle bin using c++.net(or c#.net) inside a thread. When i do this straight (without thread) it works. But if thread used it doesn't. Please watch the code snippet below:

```
namespace EmptyRecycleBin_C{
enum RecycleFlags
{
  SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x00000001,
  SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI = 0x00000002,
  SHERB_NOSOUND = 0x00000004
};
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{

[DllImport("Shell32.dll",CharSet=CharSet::Unicode)]
static System::UInt32 SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, String^ pszRootPath, RecycleFlags dwFlags);

private: void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
  Thread^ th = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::doEmpty));
  th->Start();
  //this->doEmpty(); // this line works just fine
}

private: void doEmpty()
{
  try{
        SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr::Zero, String::Empty, RecycleFlags::SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION);
     }catch(Exception^ ex)
     {Diagnostics::Debug::Write(ex->Message);}
}
};
}
```

whats the problem here...?

Comment: Can you share some details about how it does not work (exception details and similar)?

Comment: it does not throw any exception, but returns a negative value. On success(when called without any thread) returns 0. Also set [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, ...)] after calling SHEmptyRecycleBin tried to catch the error result with System.Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()) which shows "operation completed successfully" although recycle bin was not emptied.

Comment: It's returning an error code? A negative value? What's the number? Better yet: assume the negative number is actually an unsigned 32-bit value, and then convert it to hex. Then google for the hex error code (e.g. 80004005)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because threads you create execute in the default security context, not in the security context of the main thread?

See [the doc on ExecutionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx) for a hint.   You can set the ExecutionContext on your thread and re-try.

Comment: I bet it's a permissions issue.  Vista UAC could be getting in the way.  Windows 7 does auto-elevation for certain tasks so that could explain why it works on 7 and not Vista.

Comment: Chesso, the link deals with FileDialogPermission. What permission is needed for this case(the code above). If you can give a code snippet how to do this it will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you called CoInitialize from your thread?

What error code is it returning?

Answer (score 1):

Shell functions work with STA threads only, and .NET threads are MTA by default. You can set the thread to use single-apartment threading:

```
th->SetApartmentState(ApartmentState::STA);
th->Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WHY that's happening, but have you tried other threading methods?  Such as a BackgroundWorker component or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?  Does the error still happen?